# C[0,1] is not complete with respect to integral norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I know this result that C[0,1] is not a Banach Space with respect to integral norm. And I have seen many examples as well, but I am thinking about an example
$$f_n(x)=\frac{1}{nx+1}$$. Clearly the limit function of $f_n(x)$ is not continuous. Can we show that $f_n(x)$ is Cauchy in C[0,1].

Comment: It would improve your Question to be a little more explicit about what the "integral norm" means.  If it means what I think it does you should not have difficulty assessing whether the sequence is Cauchy with respect to the norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_0^{1} f_n(x)dx=\frac 1  n\int_0^{n} \frac  1 {y+1} dy=\frac 1  n \ln (n+1) \to 0$.  Hence, this sequence converges in $L^{1}$ to the continuous function $0$.  It is not a valid counter-example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer sir, but can you provide a simple function which is Cauchy but not convergence in C[0,1].

Comment: There are many examples on MSE. Consider the function which is $0$ for $x \leq \frac 1 2$ , $1$ for $x \geq \frac 1 2 +\frac  1n$ and has  a straight line graph between $\frac 1 2$ and  $\frac 1 2+\frac 1 n$. @MANI